# Placement of indefinite pronouns

Tags: pronoms

Look at the example:

> *Il **n**'a **rien** mangé* - He has eaten nothing.

From [*Collins Easy Learning French Grammar*](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/what-are-the-indefinite-pronouns-in-french)

The indefinite pronoun ***rien*** was placed according to the French usual pronoun placement — before the verb. I have seen other examples with ***tout*** being placed likewise; I can't recall one now though.
Does this placement apply to any other indefinite pronoun such as *personne, quelque chose, quelqu'une*...?

Comment: *Rien* here is a part of negation - it replaces *pas*, which in case of a composite tense should follow the (first) auxiliary verb. Thus this case is rather different from the use of *tout, quelque chose, quelqu'un* (*personne* can also be a part of negation.)

Comment: @RogerVadim: let me point out (but of course you know this already) that *personne* can also be a part of negation, but it doesn't behave like *rien* — *je n'ai rien trouvé* but *je n'ai trouvé personne*.

Comment: @PeterShor good point.

Answer (score 4):

[Kalmbach, La grammaire de l'étudiant finnophone, La place de "*rien*"](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/pron-indef.html#325)

According to this reference, which provides all there is to know, there is no particular principle involved, it is just a matter of particular  usage concerning "*rien*".

(*CVD : complément de verbe direct (COD); CVP : complément de verbe prépositionnel (COI)*)

> Les pro­noms in­dé­fi­nis occupent en général dans la phra­se la place du grou­pe no­mi­nal et ne posent pas de dif­fi­cul­tés par­ti­cu­liè­res. Le pro­nom "*rien*" a un com­por­te­ment spé­ci­fi­que.
>
> **Aux temps com­po­sés**
>
> Aux temps com­po­sés, "*rien*" CVD se place après l’au­xi­liai­re :
>
> • Tu n’as rien mangé.
> • Je n’ai rien compris.
>
> Quand "*rien*" est com­plé­té par un ad­jec­tif (auquel il est relié par "*de*") ou une structure équi­va­lente, soit il reste à sa place après l’au­xi­liaire, soit (moins fré­quem­ment) il se met, avec l’ad­jec­tif, après le ver­be :
>
> • Je n’ai rien vu d’intéressant. **ou** Je n’ai vu rien d’intéressant.
> • Je n’ai jamais rien entendu de tel. **ou** Je n’ai jamais entendu rien de tel.
> • Ils n’avaient rien découvert d’intéressant. **ou** Ils n’avaient découvert rien d’intéressant.
> • Je n’ai rien fait de spécial. **ou** Je n’ai fait rien de spécial.
>
> Quand le pro­nom est com­plé­té par l’ad­jec­tif au­tre, on peut éga­le­ment uti­li­ser les deux for­mes, mais dans le fran­çais parlé, il y a une assez nette ten­dan­ce à maintenir plutôt le groupe "*rien d’au­tre*" ensemble, et donc placé après le verbe ("*rien d’au­tre*" commence à être perçu comme un groupe figé). Mais cela dépend aus­si en par­tie des ha­bi­tu­des personnelles :
>
> • Il n’a demandé rien d’au­tre. **ou** Il n’a rien demandé d’au­tre.
> • (Français parlé) On a acheté rien d’au­tre. **ou** (code écrit) On n’a rien acheté d’au­tre.
> • La police n’avait révélé rien d’au­tre. **ou** La police n’avait rien révélé d’au­tre.
>
> **Complément d’un in­fi­ni­tif dépen­dant d’un au­tre ver­be**
>
> Le pro­nom "*rien*" CVD d’un ver­be à l’in­fi­ni­tif dépen­dant d’un au­tre ver­be se place avant tous les au­tres pro­noms qui dépendent de cet in­fi­ni­tif :
>
> •Je n’ose rien leur dire.
> • Elle ne veut rien manger.
> • Il ne va plus rien en rester.
> • Anne ne peut rien lui en dire.
> • Il ne sait rien faire.
>
> Si le ver­be dont dépend l’in­fi­ni­tif est à un temps com­po­sé, le pro­nom "*rien*" CVD se place après l’auxiliaire du ver­be dont dépend l’in­fi­ni­tif :
>
> • On n’a rien pu faire.
> • Je n’ai rien osé lui dire.
> • Anne n’a rien pu dire.
> • Il n’a rien voulu leur dire.
> • Il n’a rien su faire.
>
> Dans le fran­çais parlé, on entend cou­ram­ment placer le pro­nom après le par­ti­ci­pe :
>
> • On a pu rien faire.
> • On a voulu rien leur dire
>
> Dans les com­plé­tives avec infinitif, on maintient l’ordre normal, au­tre­ment dit "*rien*" se place entre l’auxiliaire et le par­ti­ci­pe de l’infinitif passé l’infinitif à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve.
> • Je pense n’avoir rien oublié.
> • Elle croyait n’avoir rien gardé du passé.
>
> **Ordre des mots à l’infinitif et au par­ti­ci­pe**
>
> Avec les pro­noms in­dé­fi­nis semi-né­ga­ti­fs, l’ordre des mots pose cer­tains problèmes. "*Rien*" se met normalement avant l’in­fi­ni­tif (groupé avec ne com­me dans le cas de ne pas), alors que "*personne*", "*aucun*", "*nul*" se placent après l’in­fi­ni­tif ; au par­ti­ci­pe, on observe la règle nor­ma­le :
>
> ne rien révéler / ne révélant rien
> ne voir personne / ne voyant personne
> ne prendre au­cun rendez-vous / ne prenant au­cun rendez-vous
> ne se donner nulle peine / ne se donnant nulle peine
>
> Au passé, à l’infinitif et au par­ti­ci­pe, "*rien*" se place entre l’au­xi­liai­re et le par­ti­ci­pe passé, tandis que "*personne*", "*au­cun*" et "*nul*" se placent après tout le grou­pe in­fi­ni­tif (code écrit et fran­çais parlé)  :
>
> n’avoir rien vu  / n’ayant rien vu - n’avoir rien dit / n’ayant rien dit
> pourquoi n’avoir jamais rien tenté / n’ayant jamais rien tenté.
>  n’avoir vu personne /n’ayant vu personne
> n’avoir essayé au­cu­ne au­tre solu­tion / n’ayant essayé au­cu­ne au­tre solu­tion
> n’être tombé sur au­cu­ne er­reur / n’étant tombé sur au­cu­ne er­reur
>
> **Com­plément pré­po­si­tion­nel**
>
> Quand "*rien*" est en fonc­tion de CVP, il se place après le ver­be :
>
> • Essaye de ne penser à rien.
> • Nous n’avons plus besoin de rien.